# firebase realtime database data disappeared

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I've been using firebase-realtime-database for a year now and it's been working fine. Today part of my data just disappeared. I haven't made any code changes. Is there anyway to see what happened? I do have a backup. The data was there yesterday and not today.

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: [logs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs)

Comment: There is no auditing or logging for Realtime Database.

Comment: As Doug said, there are no audit logs as the volume of data would be huge. The usual steps are to restore the data, and then figure out how it was possible that someone deleted data that they should be allowed to delete. Study your server-side security rules carefully, as those are your safeguard against unauthorized access.

Comment: The same happens to me now!